# Vuejs Hello World Wont Render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to run the Vuejs hello world on a Cloud 9 dev environment. its so simple yet I cant figure why it isn't rendering, even though there are no errors. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            new Vue({
                el: '#app'
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello World!'
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
     </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Move the script to the bottom of the body.

Comment: What do you mean there are no errors? The console shows "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" and points to line 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should appear at the bottom of the `body`. If you include it in the `head` element, it will run *before* `#app` is rendered and nothing will happen.

Also, you missed a comma after `el: "#app"`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello World!'
            }
        });
    </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: @rustyocean no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you didn't put your written file on the bottom and didn't give comma(,) between el and data that's why that script won't show the result. I hope now it's done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
     </body>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message: 'Hello World!'
           }
       });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you unless they are being picky about the script block outside the body. You are correct.

Comment: @BertEvans His answer was copy+paste from yours.

Comment: @Romoku There are differences that indicate he just came up with the same answer independently. Which is fine with me.

Comment: @Romoku i didn't copy the answer from anywhere. when i go to solved it in jsbin i think BertEvan give the answer.